# Can't find where ECMAScript mentioned the about scope chain

Tags: javascript

Hey so i've been reading lately the ecmascript spec and i've encountered a talk about LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment

like

> 1. Let oldEnv be the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment.
> 2. Let blockEnv be NewDeclarativeEnvironment(oldEnv).
> 3. Perform BlockDeclarationInstantiation(StatementList, blockEnv).
> 4. Set the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment to blockEnv.
> 5. Let blockValue be the result of evaluating StatementList.
> 6. Set the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment to oldEnv.
> 7. Return blockValue.

right the LexicalEnvironment now points to the blockEnv which is a declarative Environment Record

but it doesn't says at what place we are searching for variables.

based on logic i assume it's searching inside the LexicalEnvironment.

what i'm asking is where can i find the rule that's says the place where we are looking for variables and functions.

Answer (score 2):

The scope chain is implemented via the [[OuterEnv]] property of [environment objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-environment-records).

> Every Environment Record has an [[OuterEnv]] field, which is either null or a reference to an outer Environment Record. This is used to model the logical nesting of Environment Record values. The outer reference of an (inner) Environment Record is a reference to the Environment Record that logically surrounds the inner Environment Record.

Basically, when looking up the binding for an identifier, the current environment object is used, and if no matching binding is found, the one linked via [[OuterEnv]] is used, and so on.

You can see that in [ResolveBinding](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-resolvebinding) which uses [GetIdentifierReference](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-getidentifierreference). If GetIdentiferReference on doesn't find the binding on the environment object it's called with, it calls itself recursively with that environment's [[OuterEnv]]:

- If *env* is the value **null**, then

  - Return the Reference Record { [[Base]]: unresolvable, [[ReferencedName]]: *name*, [[Strict]]: *strict*, [[ThisValue]]: empty }.
- Let *exists* be ? *env*.HasBinding(*name*).
- If *exists* is **true**, then

  - Return the Reference Record { [[Base]]: *env*, [[ReferencedName]]: *name*, [[Strict]]: *strict*, [[ThisValue]]: empty }.
- Else,

  - Let *outer* be *env*.[[OuterEnv]].
  - Return ? GetIdentifierReference(*outer*, *name*, *strict*).

In a comment you asked why we need VariableEnvironment. We have both VariableEnvironment and LexicalEnvironment (and GlobalEnvironment, for that matter), which are all environment record objects ([1](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-additional-state-components-for-ecmascript-code-execution-contexts), [2](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-global-environment-records)). We need variable environment vs. lexical environment in order to handle `var`-scoped declarations differently from lexically-scoped declarations (`let`, `const`, etc.). For example:

```js
function example() {
    // Here, the LexicalEnvironment and the VariableEnvironment
    // are the same environment record; let's call it "outer"
    var a = 1; // Created in "outer"
    {
        // Here, there's a new environment set as the LexicalEnvironment,
        // using "outer" as its [[OuterEnv]. Let's call it "inner". See
        // https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation
        var b = 2; // Created in "outer"
        let c = 3; // Created in "inner"
        console.log(typeof a); // "number", found in "outer"
        console.log(typeof b); // "number", found in "outer"
        console.log(typeof c); // "number", found in "inner"
    }
    console.log(typeof a); // "number", found in "outer"
    console.log(typeof b); // "number", found in "outer"
    console.log(typeof c); // "undefined", not found at all
}
example();
```

Comment: so why do we need VariableEnvironment if all the works done with LexicalEnvironment. when do we look inside the VariableEnvironment ?

Comment: @AngryJohn - [VariableEnvironments](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-additional-state-components-for-ecmascript-code-execution-contexts) are environment records, they're just not the only kind. (I shouldn't have had "lexical" in my first paragraph.) We need VariableEnvironment as distinct from LexicalEnvironment to handle `var`-scoped declarations differently from lexically-scoped declarations (`let`, `const`, etc.) (and for the old `with` statement).

Comment: @AngryJohn - I've added an example that I think will help.

Comment: Yeah but if in the beginning the LE and VE are the same
environment record why do we need a copy ?
yes when we call the function example a new LE will get created
that will point to a function ER.
and all the vars in that function will get hoisted to that function ER and when we will reach
the block in your example a new DER will be created and now LE will be pointing to that DER.
the new DER[[OuterEnv]] will be pointed to the old Env which in these case is the function ER.
after we reach the end of the block LE will be pointed back to the function ER so what's the point of that VE.

Comment: by the way sorry if my english sounds like a 6 year old kid is talking. english isn't my first language (:

Comment: @AngryJohn A direct `eval` call (in sloppy mode, at least) may add new variables to the VariableEnvironment. Also, legacy semantics for block-scoped function declarations.

Comment: @AngryJohn - (Thanks for the English note; your'e fine. :-) ) I'm afraid I don't know what you mean about a copy. There's no copying of environment records that I'm aware of. The VE holds the var-scoped bindings for the execution context created by calling the function (in my example). The LE is required for the block to handle lexical declarations in the block. I don't have time now, but I'll come back later to walk through the example above extended a bit.

Comment: @AngryJohn - Actually, I think it's already fairly detailed. If you have any other specific questions on the above, please feel free to ping me. :-) Happy coding!

Comment: Hey @T.J.Crowder can you take a look at my latest question "How the evaluate operation works in ecmascript?"